# Why can't I use sudo on OpenBSD?

Tags: sudo, openbsd

I'm running OpenBSD 5.7 on VirtualBox on my Windows 7, to learn more about Unix, but I can't use `sudo` with my password. I've set up a user called `adminvpn` but when I try to run any command using `sudo` it tells that my password is wrong!

I have already tried my root password and my user password and I'm 100% sure they are correct and they are only letters... I have reinstalled OpenBSD 3 times and this is driving me crazy.

When I try to use my password for "adminvpn" I get

> adminvpn is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported.

I'm able to log in with root and using my root password. I'm almost giving up to running it with a user.

Comment: Persist, it gets easier: There is a bit of a learning curve. You can choose to pretend the command line does not exist, then Unix is like MS-Windows, but a bit more consistent, and not prone to mood swings. Or you can learn the command line, as you do you will slowly become more powerful, eventually you will be able to do anything.

Comment: fyi, nowadays OpenBSD use https://man.openbsd.org/doas.1 and not sudo. The original documentation for a website should be always better than an outdated forum question. sudo is irrelevant on OpenBSD now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message tells you what is wrong even if it doesn't tell you exactly how to fix it.

> adminvpn is not in the sudoers file.

`sudo` lets you run commands as the administrator. In order to be able to use sudo, you need to be made an administrator. Accounts are not made administrators by default.

Run the command [`visudo`](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-5.7/visudo) (as root, of course) and add a line like the following:

```
adminvpn ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Save the file and exit. You can now run any command as root with `sudo`.

Note that `visudo` will run your favorite editor, as indicated by the environment variable `VISUAL`. If you haven't configured that, you'll get vi. If you're uncomfortable with vi, install [another editor](https://pkgsrc.se/editors) (e.g. `pkg_add nano`) and add a line like `export VISUAL=nano` to `~/.profile`; run the command in your interactive shell as well for it to take effect in the current session.

Unless configured otherwise, `sudo` requires you to type your own password. Knowledge of the root password is not necessary, that's the point of `sudo`. The point of typing your password is to make sure it isn't someone else typing while you left your keyboard unattended.

By the way, OpenBSD isn't the most beginner-friendly Unix out there. If you want a gentler learning curve, try Ubuntu.

Comment: You will note that `/etc/sudoers` probably has the entry `%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`. If so then you only need add a user to group `sudo`, no need to edit `/etc/sudoers`.

Comment: To run visudo using nano (without pre-config in `~/.profile)`: first install nano, then `EDITOR=nano visudo`.

Comment: @richard Is that `%sudo` line present on OpenBSD these days? It isn't on my admittedly old VM with OpenBSD 4.8, sudo 1.7.2. If it is, then @Freedom, you can add yourself to the `sudo` group by running `usermod -G sudo adminvpn`, then logging out and back in.

Comment: I have no idea, it does on Debian 6, but don't know about OpenBSD. That is why I used a conditional clause in the comment. I also put it for other Unixers that way pass this way.

Comment: I assume i must add it under the line " # User Privilege Specification " right? I'm doing this right now if works i'll accept the answer thanks! By the way i'm trying to learn this to set up my own vpn and secure cloud storage with a dedicated server i'll rent later...i was told that i should use OpenBSD for that...i don't think i can(or should?) do that in Ubuntu?

Comment: Anything you can do in OpenBSD can be done in Ubuntu.  (There may be some weird special case, but I don't know of any.) However, OpenBSD is governed by its maintainers with a special focus on security and reliability. As such, it's an excellent choice for your goal.

Comment: @Freedom You can do that in Ubuntu. The security argument can go both ways: OpenBSD has more of a focus on security but that doesn't make all that much difference in practice, especially given that Ubuntu has easy security updates whereas OpenBSD doesn't (so security updates are rarer, but harder to apply). OpenBSD has a smaller attack surface by default, but if you end up misconfiguring something manually rather than using Ubuntu's default secure configuration for the same feature, that's not a gain.

Comment: @Gilles Could you create a chat for us ? I want to ask a few things i'm having problem now if that's is not asking too much of course !! You appear to be very good with unix systems

Comment: @Freedom I'm not going to be available for chat much this week. Just drop by the main Unix.SE chat and see whoever's around.

Comment: @richard @gilles - on openbsd the equivalent sudo group is `wheel`.
@Freedom - fyi, the _sudoers_ file has a `man` page too, with many more details

Comment: *"If you want a gentler learning curve, try Ubuntu."* Or even FreeBSD. OpenBSD is probably the *least* newbie-friendly \*nix available to commoners. FreeBSD still won't do much in terms of holding your hand and walk you through the basics, but at least a default installation is reasonably usable out of the box (ISO?). Also, I consider the FreeBSD documentation to be *exemplary*.

Answer (score 4):

[OpenBSD 5.8](http://www.openbsd.org/58.html) or later comes with **[doas](http://man.openbsd.org/doas)** instead of **sudo** (which remains available as a package), and by default it's not configured to let you run things.

Create file `/etc/doas.conf` and add to it:

```
permit persist adminvpn as root
permit persist keepenv root as root
```

The first line lets *adminvpn* do as *root*.
The seconds one lets *root* do as *root*. While it looks silly, it's for the convenience of being able to run commands with the `doas` "prefix" both as *adminvpn* and *root*. Without it you'd need to run the plain command if you're already logged in as *root*.

If you need to let *adminvpn* run commands as different users, you can add additional `permit` lines to the file.

Then you can do:

```sh
doas my-privileged-command
```

to run `my-privileged-command` as *root*.

Thanks to [Kusalananda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/116858/kusalananda) for the helpful comment.

Comment: Note that `doas` was introduced in OpenBSD 5.8, and that the question is about `sudo` on OpenBSD 5.7.  The issue is not about `doas` but with correct configuration of `sudo`. Also note that OpenBSD still has `sudo` as a package.

Comment: This worked for me perfectly, thanks!